# How to get approximate float value in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The value of A is

```
A = 0.4000070095062256
```

and after that I have the below code to check the value of A

```
if (A == 0.400):
    print('pass')
else:
    print('Fail')
```

I want to print `Pass`. The above code is printing `Fail` every time. How will i get approx value of A??

Note: In the condition I have to check the value of A with exactly equal to `0.400`. and I mean to say I need approx value of A in float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check, if the distance to `0.4` is less than a given limit, e.g.:

```
if abs(A - 0.4) < 0.0001:
    print("Pass")
```